# Why are my dropdown elements to the left of my buttons not underneath?

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to create drop-down menus under the various categories but whenever I hover over them, the dropdown menu appears to the left of the button. Any suggestions on how to fix? Link to my code below

Here is jsFiddle link:

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.content {
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.donate {
  background-color: orange;
  border: white;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding: 7px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.donate:hover {
  background-color: rgb(102, 51, 0);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.divnav {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropbtn {
  font-size: 13px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: inherit;
  float: right;
  display: block;
  margin: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-weight: 550;
}

.dropbtn:hover {
  color: orange;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

html {}

.image {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.navbar {
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.navelement {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  margin: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 550;
}

.nava {
  padding: 5px;
}

.nava:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: orange;
}

.pagetitle {
  height: 68px;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url("pictures/titlebar1.jpg");
}

.par {
  /* DIV THAT GOES UNDER TODOCONTENT ONLY AND MARKS A PARAGRAPH WITH INFORMATIVE CONTENT*/
}

.parcontent {
  font-family: verdana;
  color: rgb(150, 150, 150);
  font-size: 15px;
}

.titleimage {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 310px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

.title {
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
}

.todocontent {
  width: 47%;
  /* A DIV WITH CLASS TODOCONTENT MEANS A DIV THAT WILL CONTAIN ALL INFORMATIVE CONTENT OF THE PAGE*/
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="titleimage">
  <img src="C:\Users\kiran.nair\Desktop\Internship\current\pictures\heading2.jpg" alt="GLI.logo" style="width:100%;height:100%;">
</div>
<div class="divnav">
  <div class="wrapper" style="POSITION: absolute; TOP: 300px; LEFT: 0px;">
    <img src="C:\Users\kiran.nair\Desktop\Internship\current\pictures\wrapper.png" alt="wrapper" style="width:20000px;height:5px;">
  </div>
  <div style="POSITION: relative; TOP: 20px; LEFT: 15%;">
    <img src="C:\Users\kiran.nair\Desktop\Internship\current\pictures\GLI.logo.png" alt="GLI.logo" style="width:145px;height:152px;">
  </div>
  <div style="POSITION: relative; TOP: -20px; LEFT: 10%;">
    <ul class="navbar">
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">CONTACT</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content" style="POSITION: relative; TOP: 20px;">
          <a href="#">contact</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">RESEARCH</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content" style="POSITION: relative; TOP: 10px;">
          <a href="#">research</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">TRIP PREP</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content" style="POSITION: relative; TOP: 10px;">
          <a href="#">TRIP PREP</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">UPCOMING EVENTS</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content" style="POSITION: relative; TOP: 10px;">
          <a href="#">UPCOMING EVENTS</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">MEDIA</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content" style="POSITION: relative; TOP: 10px;">
          <a href="#">MEDIA</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">ENTUSI EVENTS</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content" style="POSITION: relative; TOP: 10px;">
          <a href="#">ENTUSI EVENTS</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">PROGRAMS</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content" style="POSITION: relative; TOP: 10px;">
          <a href="#">PROGRAMS</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">ABOUT</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content" style="POSITION: relative; TOP: 10px;">
          <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">HOME</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content" style="POSITION: relative; TOP: 10px;">
          <a href="#">HOME</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="divdonate" style="POSITION: relative; TOP: -140px; LEFT: 80%;">
    <button class="donate">DONATE NOW</button>
  </div>
</div>

<body>

  <div>
    <div class="pagetitle">
      <div>
        <header class="title" style="POSITION: relative; LEFT: 15%">Uganda</header>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="todocontent" style="POSItiON: relative; TOP: 15%; LEFT: 15%;">
      <div class="par" style="POSITION: relative; TOP: 15%; LEFT: 0%;">
        <p class="parcontent">
          Uganda was formed from the colonization of the Buganda Kingdom by the British in the 19th century. Britain wanted to protect the viability of the Nile River for its trading potential which prompted the British government to annex Buganda to create the
          Uganda Protectorate in 1894. In 1962 Uganda regained its independence and declared itself a republic with Milton Obote as the first prime minister and former Bugandan King Muteesa as the president. Despite being largely ceremonial, Obote removed
          the presidential position and established a new constitution in which he became a powerful president similar to a dictator. After committing many atrocities Obote was removed from power in a coup orchestrated by General Idi Amin who seized control
          of the country. Amin proceeded to be nearly as atrocious as Obote when almost 500,000 citizens perished under his regime. Despite entering presidency with cheers, his actions made the country of Uganda hate him. After Amin was removed from power
          by largely Tanzanian forces, Obote returned to presidency. A war broke out as a result from the election resulting in the deaths of between 100 and 500,000 people. This compelled 2 military commanders to conduct a coup in which Museveni gained
          control. Yoweri Museveni remains in power till this date."
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Images don't work but shouldn't matter right?

Answer (score 0):

You should remove inline styles that you inserted for all elements with class `.dropdown-content`.

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">CONTACT</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content" style="POSITION: relative; TOP: 20px;">
        <a href="#">contact</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is called inline style. Style written directly on html element:

```
style="POSITION: relative; TOP: 20px;"
```

Next, you need to modify rule for `.dropdown-content`:

```
.dropdown-content{
    /* Your code here */
    top: 100%; 
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I'm very new to html5 but what do you mean by removing inline styles for elements with class .dropdown-content? I don't think I have style: inline-block; within .dropdown-content